# How do I attach a bash shell to a named pipe?

Tags: bash, fifo

Let’s say I have two containers X and Y (two containers in the same Kubernetes pod, actually) that share a volume. On that volume is a named pipe `/foo` that I want attached to a bash process on container Y. As container X sends data to container Y, I want it to work the same way the e.g., `ssh` works: the command should be read by the remote bash shell, and pipes and whatnot are handled transparently.

I’ve tried the following on machine Y:

- `bash -s <> /foo`: If from machine X I run `echo “ls -l” > /foo; cat /foo` then the command is run on Y, but the output goes to Y’s terminal and not to the named pipe
- `bash -s < /foo > /foo` If from machine X I run `echo “ls -l” > /foo; cat /foo` then nothing happens
- `bash -s < /foo | cat - > foo`: If from machine X I run `echo “ls -l” > /foo; cat /foo` then the command is run on Y, the output appears on X’s terminal, and then no further commands are executed on Y and X hangs.

It could be that what I’m looking for is a way to attach the current shell on X to the named pipe, and on X attach it to a new shell. Again, I’d like it to work like `ssh` does, where you can connect and send a single non-interactive command (or script) and/or pipe data, and somehow it works the way you’d expect. I just haven’t figured out the proper shell fu to make it happen.

Also I don’t understand why the three options above produce different results.

Comment: A pipe is unidirectional, a single stream. `ssh`, when it doesn't allocate a tty on the remote side, passes data from its stdin to the stdin of the remote command; it receives data the remote command prints to its (i.e. remote) stdout and stderr, and prints locally to its own stdout and stderr respectively. So you need *three* pipes. You can drop stderr or merge the remote stdout and stderr, still you need at least two pipes: at least one pipe per direction. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't think the word "machine" is appropriate here.  A _named pipe_ or FIFO file only works to connect file descriptors of two processes both running in the same kernel.  They're effectively the same as an AF_LOCAL socket (i.e. a Unix domain socket).  If we assume each _machine_ runs its own separate stand-alone kernel, then a process on machine 'X' cannot communicate with a process on machine 'Y' through a named pipe, even if they both mount the same filesystem where the named pipe FIFO file exists, e.g. with some kind of network filesystem (e.g. NFS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, with the help of telometto, Kamil and Greg A. Woods, I arrived at the following solution, which seems to meet my needs:

- On the shared volume, create *three* named pipes, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`
- On machine Y, run `while true; do bash -s < stdin 2> stderr > stdout ; done`
- On machine X I created a helper script to help run remote commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM

(
  echo "$@"
  if read -t 0 ; then
    cat - 2> /dev/null
  fi
) | cat > stdin

cat stdout &
cat stderr > /dev/stderr &

wait
```

To use it, you simply `./run "ls -l"` from X and the command is run on Y. You can also `./run "cat > bar" < foo` from X and the command is run on Y, moving (in this case) the contents of `foo` from X to Y along the way. Piped input is handled similarly.

Comment: Excellent :-) Please don't forget to drop by after 48 hours to accept your answer. That prevents it from appearing as "Unanswered" in the future, and helps others facing similar issue.

Comment: Both instances of `cat` are entirely superfluous.  `bash -s < stdin > stdout 2> stderr`

Answer (score 2):

To attach a bash shell to a named pipe, you can use the `exec` command to replace the current shell process with a new one that is connected to the named pipe. E.g. how you can do this on machine Y:

```bash
cat /foo | bash
```

This will replace the current shell process with a new one that reads from and writes to the named pipe `/foo`. Now, any commands or data sent from machine X to `/foo` will be read by the new shell process on machine Y.

Regarding your three attempts and the different results:

1. `bash -s <> /foo`: This command runs a new shell process that reads from standard input and writes to standard output. The `<>` syntax tells the shell to open the named pipe for both reading and writing. When you run `echo "ls -l" > /foo` on machine X, it writes the string "ls -l" to the named pipe, which is then read by the new shell process on machine Y. The command is executed on Y, but the output is printed to Y's terminal instead of being written to the named pipe.
2. `bash -s < /foo > /foo`: This command runs a new shell process that reads from the named pipe and writes to the named pipe. When you run `echo "ls -l" > /foo` on machine X, it writes the string "ls -l" to the named pipe, which is then read by the new shell process on machine Y. However, the shell process is also writing to the same named pipe, which creates a deadlock and causes nothing to happen.
3. `bash -s < /foo | cat - > foo`: This command runs a new shell process that reads from the named pipe and pipes its output to the cat command, which writes to a regular file `foo`. When you run `echo "ls -l" > /foo` on machine X, it writes the string "ls -l" to the named pipe, which is then read by the new shell process on machine Y. The command is executed on Y, and the output appears on X's terminal because it is being written to the cat process running on X. However, the cat process does not write anything back to the named pipe, which causes the new shell process on machine Y to hang.

Comment: `bash < /foo > /foo` is absurd. Any pipe is unidirectional, there's just one stream. The command makes `bash` read and interpret whatever enters the pipe, including *its own output*. When this `bash` runs, `echo "ls -l" > /foo` may be harmless, but don't try `echo ls > /foo`.